# Как вывести дату и время на экран?

Tags: время, java, дата

Сейчас прохожу дату и время. Не могу попросту вывести дату и время на экран. Пожалуйста, объясните, что к чему.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте метод `Date.toString()` - это самый простой и верный способ

**Update**

Если нужно что-то более извращенное, то есть класс `SimpleDateFormat`, примеры обращения с ним [здесь](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помог!

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы обновлялось в реальном времени(где-то видел, но на php)

Answer (score 2):

Печатает текущую дату на "экран":

```
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

**UPDATE**: результат выполнения кода:

```
Sat Aug 18 00:11:32 EEST 2012
```

Comment: Это будет кол. миллисекунд, прошедших с Epoch-а

Comment: > Это будет кол. миллисекунд, прошедших с Epoch-а
Боюсь вас удивить, но время это относительная величина. Точка отсчета может быть разной. А код выводит дату, а не количество мс :)

Comment: Фактически это и есть неявный вызов `Date.toString()` :)

Comment: Разве я отрицал это? :)

Answer (score -1):

<?=date(Y)?>

Comment: Вопрос был про Яву, но спасибо